# Is there a way to update nuget package with multiple interdependent dependencies to a newer version in an old csproj format project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, nuget

We have a Visual Studio solution with [old(pre VS2017)](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) format csproj projects with dependency on [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient 15.112.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/15.112.1) that has a fair share of other (inter)dependencies it requires.

The problem is that even in a new standalone project it is impossible to update (in VS2017) dependency to the newer [15.131.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/15.131.1) version. There is always the **following error** (regardless of the options I try):

```
PM> Update-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient

Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project 'TestTfsNugetUpdate', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Gathering dependency information took 6.98 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Update-Package : Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Common 15.112.1 constraint: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client (= 
15.112.1)'.At line:1 char:1
```

While the same standalone [new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) format project has no such issues

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net45</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" Version="15.112.1" />
  </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```

As

```
Update-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient -DependencyVersion Highest
Restoring packages for C:\Projects\TEST\TestTfsNugetUpdate\TestTfsNugetPackage_NewFormat\TestTfsNugetPackage_NewFormat.csproj...
Installing NuGet package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient 15.131.1.
...
Successfully installed 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.1.5' to TestTfsNugetPackage_NewFormat
Executing nuget actions took 97.55 ms
```

So, basically is there a way to do it with old format project without resorting to manual/semiautomatic removal and reinstallation of the ExtendedClient with dependencies (the problem is that the solution includes a lot of projects that may or may not depend on TFS dlls, so I can't just remove+install it for each project)?

P.S.: Porting everything to a new format is a nice idea in any case, but it is not something I'd like to undertake at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to update nuget package with multiple interdependent dependencies to a newer version in an old csproj format project?

I am sorry for this late reply, I am not sure if this answer is helpful to you.

I could reproduce this issue on my side, but it seems we have to uninstall and reinstall the version `15.131.1`.

Just like you said, the package `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` has multiple interdependent dependencies, like:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client (= 15.112.1)

Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client (= 15.112.1)
```

**However**, the dependencies `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` also has a indirect dependence `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client (= 15.112.1)`. When we update the package `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`, nuget will update package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client (= 15.112.1)` first, but package `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client (= 15.112.1)` still reference it, will prevent us from updating the package.

The reverse is the same. Multiple interdependent dependencies of this package form a deadlock, we could not break it for now unless we upgrade every dependencies with option ignore dependencies.

So, we have to uninstall and reinstall the version `15.131.1`.

> the problem is that the solution includes a lot of projects that may
>   or may not depend on TFS dlls, so I can't just remove+install it for
>   each project

You can use the option **Manage Nuget packages for solution...**, and select the project checkbox, all the project which installed that package will be selected:

[image]

So, you do not need uninstall and reinstall the package for each project one by one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about the "for Solution" option, though I (mostly, barring some recalcitrant cases) automated the process through PackageManagerConsole commands (`Get-Project -All | Where...`).